# Certification path building for 509 certificates

Tags: certificate-authority, x.509

To this date, is there a specification or a de-facto industry standard or how applications are supposed to perform certification path building in the context of X.509? I am specifically asking about the part of the certification path building process that retrieves all the necessary certificates.

> Certification path building is the process by which the certificate
> processing system obtains the certification path between a trust
> anchor and the target certificate. [RFC 3280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4158#:%7E:text=2.%20%20Certification%20Path,of%20PKI%20structures.)

[1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4158#:%7E:text=2.%20%20Certification%20Path,of%20PKI%20structures.) is a 2005 informational RFC about the topic but it's not "Standard" nor "Best Current Practice".

Wikipedia mentions that, at least in the early days of 509 certs, a server would send all the required certificates:

> [...] The problem is the client does not know where to fetch missing intermediate certificates because the global X.500 directory never materialized.[...] To work around the problem, web servers now send all the intermediate certificates along with the web server's certificate. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#:%7E:text=An%20early%20issue,web%20server%27s%20certificate.)

Moreover, from online sources, I gathered that applications (e.g. web broswers) are preconfigured with intermediate certificates.

Finally, I came across Authority Information Access ([AIA](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#page-49:%7E:text=4.2.2.1.%20%20Authority%20Information%20Access)) which seems to be a standard feature a client could use to retrieve missing intermediate certificates. But again, this fetures is not mandatory and I found examples of it sometimes being implemented, sometimes not. [Medium article on AIA](https://akamath32.medium.com/certificate-authority-information-access-aia-7bc56f7257fc).

I listed 3 ways to perform Certification Path Building (receive the certs form the server, certs hardcoded in the applicaiton and AIA). But is there a standard?

Comment: _For SSL/TLS_ including web (HTTPS) all standards (6101, 2246, 4346, 5246, 8446) require server send all intermediates and make it optional to send root. No browser I know of is configured with intermediates, so your 'sources' are wrong; browsers either are configured with _roots_ (Firefox/Tor at least by default) or use an OS-provided store which is configured with roots (Chrome/Edge/Brave/Opera, Safari, IE before it vanished). But remember web&browsers are not the only use of SSL/TLS and SSL/TLS not the only use of X.509 certificates, and other uses are often different.

Comment: Compare https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211749/where-do-tls-clients-fetch-intermediate-ca-certificates-from https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64415/how-are-browsers-able-to-find-and-construct-an-alternate-trusted-chain-path https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65332/ssl-root-certificate-optional

Comment: Thanks, your comment was helpful, I was looking for a standard in the 509 spec but I didn't consider to look for this in the TLS spec.

Comment: OP, @dave_thompson_085 is correct that browsers are not *configured* with intermediate certificates, per se.  However, Firefox [maintains a local cache of preloaded intermediate certificates](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/CryptoEngineering/Intermediate_Preloading), which it updates regularly.  Not sure if other browsers do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Modern web browsers will use all three of the methods that you described to try to build a valid chain of trust up to a root certificate that it trusts.  These multiple ways of validating certificates are what enable us to have [cross-signed certificates](https://scotthelme.co.uk/cross-signing-alternate-trust-paths-how-they-work/).

Related:  [What could cause classic "ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID" when I can confirm no error from numerous other clients?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/258190/what-could-cause-classic-err-cert-date-invalid-when-i-can-confirm-no-error-fro)